# Find sum of positive geometric progression numbers

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a task to get the total number of games played in a soccer tournament. Apart from the group stages, I observed that the number of games played in each round from the knockout round down to the final round is `n/2` games where `n = number of teams`. An easy way of getting the number of games from the knockout stage to the final according to my observation would be by summing up the geometric sequence positive integers like `n/2 + (n/2)/2 + ...`. How can I achieve this please ?

Comment: One team wins all games and the rest lose exactly one game.  Therefore the number of games played is $n-1$ no matter if $n$ is a multiple of 2 or not.

Comment: @JimB Your formula is not valid for zero number of teams: for $n=0$ the number of games is $0$, and not $-1$ as your formula suggests.

Comment: This is one of those beloved-by-some-kinds-of-interviewer trick questions.  The answer is as @JimB has commented.  Anyone starting off along the lines of summing a geometric series fails the interview!

Comment: @yarchik That's ridiculous - only if the impossibility of a world-wide pandemic occurred or the soon-to-occur zombie apocalypse would $n=0$ make sense.;).

Comment: @JimB Just joking :) . In fact, I like your quick comment very much. By the way, a `Sum` with the `GenerateConditions` option takes care that.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark "Anyone starting off along the lines of summing a geometric series fails the interview!"... reference von Neumann...Train-Fly question...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way which makes use of your formula

```
numGames[n_] := Block[{rounds},
  rounds = Log[2, n];
  If[!IntegerQ@rounds, Print["bad bracket"]; Abort[];,
   Sum[n/2^i, {i, rounds}]]]
```

We assume the number of teams is a power of $2$ so you can keep dividing by $2$ each round. If it's not, we quit. Otherwise we do your sum,
$$n/2+n/2/2+n/2/2/2+\dots=n/2+n/2^2+n/2^3+\dots=\sum_i n/2^i$$

So if we run `numGames[64]` we get $63$ back. As @BobHanlon mentions, we get $n-1$ games for $n$ players. We can see this directly with

```
Sum[n/2^i, {i, Log[2, n]}]
```

which gives $n-1$

Answer (score 0):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

In the tournament, `{CumulativeGamesPlayed, TeamsAdvancing}` evolves as

```
FixedPointList[{#[[1]] + Floor[#[[2]]/2], Ceiling[#[[2]]/2]} &, {0, 7}]

(* {{0, 7}, {3, 4}, {5, 2}, {6, 1}, {6, 1}} *)
```

Then the sequence of `{n, CumulativeGamesPlayed}` is given by

```
seq = Table[{n, 
   FixedPoint[{#[[1]] + Floor[#[[2]]/2], Ceiling[#[[2]]/2]} &, {0, 
      n}][[1]]}, {n, 2, 15}]

(* {{2, 1}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}, {6, 5}, {7, 6}, {8, 7}, {9, 8}, {10, 9}, {11,
   10}, {12, 11}, {13, 12}, {14, 13}, {15, 14}} *)
```

Generalizing from the sequence,

```
games[n_Integer?Positive] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n]

(* -1 + n *)
```

There are one fewer games played than the number of teams

For `n == 7`

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 8, 2 -> 8, 3 -> 9, 4 -> 9, 5 -> 10, 6 -> 10, 7 -> 11, 8 -> 12, 
  9 -> 12, 10 -> 13, 11 -> 13, 12 -> 14, 13 -> 14}, Bottom, 
 VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

For `n == 8`

```
TreePlot[{1 -> 9, 2 -> 9, 3 -> 10, 4 -> 10, 5 -> 11, 6 -> 11, 7 -> 12, 
  8 -> 12, 9 -> 13, 10 -> 13, 11 -> 14, 12 -> 14, 13 -> 15, 14 -> 15}, Bottom,
  VertexLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- In a final two teams play and one wins. Let us call this play a stage *zero* because it is very important.
- In semifinals four teams play and two win. Let us call this stage
  *one*.
- In quarterfinals eight teams play and four win. Let us call this
  stage *two*.
- In one-eights of a final sixteen teem play and eight win. Call this stage *three*.

There are not many soccer [tournaments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-elimination_tournament) with more stages. Thus, highest stage is $s=3$. Now we can make a table:

```
Stage(s) Teams(n) Wins(w) Games(g) Name 
0        2        1       1        Final
1        4        2       2        Semifinals
2        8        4       4        Quarterfinals
3       16        8       8        One-eights of a final
```

Now everything is easy:

- Each game has a winner in a single-elimination tournament. Therefore the number of winners is equal to the number of games $w = g$.
- Number of winners at the stage $s$ is equal to $w=g=2^s\; (s\ge0)$. This can be appreciated from the table, or one can use [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to prove this equation.
- Now we can use the power of Mathematica to compute the total number of games in a tournament starting from stage $s$:

---

```
gtotal = Sum[2^i, {i, 0, s}, GenerateConditions -> True]
(* ConditionalExpression[-1 + 2^(1 + s), Element[s, Integers] && s >= 0] *)
```

Finally, the total number of teams $n$ is equal twice the number of winners, i.e., $n=2 w$. This product too can be computed with Mathematica

```
n = 2 2^s
(* 2^(1 + s)*)
```

---

By making use of the two last calculations we arrive at the conclusion that

$$g_\text{total} = n - 1, \quad n>0.$$

This is the answer suggested by @JimB in the comment. However, it was not appreciated that it is only valid for $n>0$. For zero number of teams ($n=0$) there are $g_\text{total}=0$ games. However, there could be a game for the [third place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_place_playoff). In this case we add one to the result above and obtain
$$g_\text{total with small final} = 1 + g_\text{total} = n,\quad n>0.$$